# windows phone 8.1 facebook unable to logout for connecting defferent user

Tags: .net, logout, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Facebook and FacebookClient packages.

In my application I successfully logged in to my user by this code line:

```
session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me");
```

but even if I make before:

```
                    App.FacebookSessionClient.Logout();
```

I still are connected to the same user as before.

How can I logout to connect an other user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the Cookies. After the Logout() method, call:

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```